# Hiding ActionBar from ActionBarActivity after a Splash Fragment

Tags: java, android

Basically the launcher is the ActionBarActivity that calls the Fragment(splash) and then back to ActionBarActivity. THe problem is before the splash became visible the actionbar shows up and then the splash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what you want is to remove the actionbar when your splashscreen loads?. Try put this item inside your current theme on **res/values/styles.xml**

```
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

It goes like this for example:

```
 <style name="MyActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <!-- other activity and action bar styles here -->
</style>
```

I hope it helps. :)

Comment: NullPointerException since it needs to call getSupportActionBar()

Comment: I think i got it, from setting the theme first(my main theme for all, this one i added a windowNoTitle = false) and in my manifest the launcher activity has a theme with attribute windowNoTitle = true.

Comment: Yes **<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>** should go into your current theme used for that specific activity or for the whole application. Like for my case i use **android:theme="@style/MyActivityTheme"** for my SplashScreen activity in the Manifest.

Comment: The `android` namespace doesn't work. Removing it removes the title as well

Answer (score 5):

it'very simple if you are using it from support android sdk 7 then

getSupportActionBar().hide();

else

getActionBar().hide();

Comment: im using hide, yet it only covers the fragment's actionbar not the calling activity's actionbar

Answer (score 0):

create a theme that has windowNoTitle = true and use this style in the activity's manifest.
Inside the Activity(the launcher one) setTheme(you're normal one, this one i added windowNoTitle= false), add this line before the super.onCreate().